# to assign [vehicle_type = all types] when no filter is selected

Tags: oracle

I have to extract from a table based on user input, I have a table named "Vehicle_Register" with vehicle details and users are allowed to filter the data using vehicle type(car, bus, truck...). If no filer is selected all the data should be displayed.

Now for this I have to use two queries, 1 with filter and 2 for all,
1. select * from vehicle_register where vehicle_type = 'car';
2. select * from vehicle_register;

Can these two queries be merged, just want to know how to use a conditional where clause using "case" or "if" statement but to assign [vehicle_type = all types] when no filter is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * 
from vehicle_register
where (vehicle_type = mycar or mycar is null);
```

where `mycar` is a variable with your filter (can be empty if it is not set up).